# Serializing and displaying same XML file to the web browser in one button

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc-4, serialization, browser

As the topic says, i want to serialize an object as well as showing it on a web browser.
When trying to do that i get an error "IOException was unhandled by user code". The process cannot access to >... local map.

So what i have noticed is that during the serialization, its unlikely to write the same file at the same time. However. Is it somehow possible to First, Serialize it. Then Open it up?
Or is there a better solution?

```
public ActionResult Serializing(Models.SerializerModel model)
{
    var username = model.Username.ToString();
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        string path = Server.MapPath("~/xml");

        XmlSerializer serial = new XmlSerializer(model.GetType());
        System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(path + "\\"+ username + ".xml");
        serial.Serialize(writer, model);
        //This code below i want to execute after the above one is done
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.ContentType = "application/xml";
        //During WriteFile i get the error IO
        Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath("~/xml\\hello.xml"));
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Profile");

    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Profile");
}
```

The code works if i separate The response codes and the serialize code into 2 different buttons, but that is not what i want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `IOException` because your write stream is still open while you start reading it to push it in response. I have made couple of changes in your code. This should solve your problem. Also I am not sure if you really need `Response.End()` call

```
public ActionResult Serializing(Models.SerializerModel model)
{
    var username = model.Username.ToString();
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        string path = Server.MapPath("~/xml");
        //First write to file. using statement will take care of closing writer stream. 
        XmlSerializer serial = new XmlSerializer(model.GetType());
        using (var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(path + "\\" + username + ".xml"))
        {
            serial.Serialize(writer, model);
            writer.Flush();
        }

        //This code below i want to execute after the above one is done
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.ContentType = "application/xml";
        //During WriteFile i get the error IO
        Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath("~/xml/hello.xml"));
        Response.Flush();
        //Response.End();   I am not sure if this statement is really needed here.
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Profile");

    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Profile");
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It solved my problem. The only thing i had to do of the code that u wrote, was to uncomment the Response.End() code. I needed it. Otherwise. Thank you for the quick respond! Saved my day.